# TikZ foreach loop fails when the list doesn't end with a comma

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, compilation-error

The following LaTeX document is saved in a file whose path is `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{ square/.pic={\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);} }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {
      square,
   }{\pic {\i};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed at the terminal:

> cd ~
> pdflatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: A square]

If the comma is now deleted after the second occurrence of the word `square` in the document at `~/test.tex`, so that the `\foreach` structure looks like this:

```
\foreach \i in {
  square
}{\pic {\i};}
```

and the command `pdflatex test` is rerun, the execution fails, and the file `~/test.log` contains the following snippet:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/square ' and I am go
ing to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10    }{\pic {\i};}
                     
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10    }{\pic {\i};}
                     
End of file on the terminal!
```

Why does the execution fail in the second case? Is this a bug in PGF/TikZ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug but an inconvenience: You need to end the line with `%`, i.e. `square%`so that the end-of-line doesn't get picked up as a space.

Comment: Just a more elaborate way to repeat what Qrrbrbirlbel already stated: The reason for the error to show is that the line break after `square` becomes a space, but `square ` (with trailing space) is not known to Ti*k*Z, as the error suggests. If you add a comma, the list contains in fact two items, the first now being `square` (without space) and the second being empty (since it only contains whitespace) and therefore ignored. If you write `\foreach \i in {square}{ \pic {\i}; }` without line breaks inside the list, the error won't appear.

Comment: `\pic[pic type/.expand once=\i];` (no `{}`!) doesn't break because PGFkeys removes the space at some point when calling the pic's code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaces before commas are not ignored in the “list” argument to `\foreach`. You'd get the same error with

```
\foreach \i in {square , square}{...}
```

and you do have a space after `square` in your input, generated by the endline.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in { square , circle}{X\i X\endgraf}

\foreach \i in {1 ,...,4}{X\i X\endgraf}

\end{document}
```

and you get

[image]

I'd call this a misfeature, if not a bug, especially in the second case, where Ti*k*Z is able to detect a range, but the first item is spaced nonetheless.

Input such as

```
\foreach \i in {1,... ,4}{ whatever }
```

leads to the low-level error

```
Runaway argument?
4\pgffor@@stop \expandafter \pgffor@dots@charcheck \pgffor@dotsvalue \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@dots@stripcontext was complete.
```

Always remove spaces before commas in such lists and protect the last element against an endline, if the closing brace is on the next line.

Comment: "misfeature, if not a bug" -- yes!