# TikZ foreach loop fails when the list doesn't end with a comma (Part II)

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, compilation-error

The following question is closely related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664485/21685), however the solution given in [the answer to that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664504/21685) does not work for the LaTeX document to be presented below, and therefore I've had to create this other post.

---

The following LaTeX document is saved in a file whose path is `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\placepics}[1]{ \foreach \i in { #1 } { \pic {\i}; } }
\tikzset{ square/.pic={\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);} }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \placepics{
      square,
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed at the terminal:

> cd ~
> pdflatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: A square]

If the comma is now deleted after the second occurrence of the word `square` in the document at `~/test.tex`, so that the `\foreach` structure looks like this:

```
\foreach \i in {
  square
}{\pic {\i};}
```

and the command `pdflatex test` is rerun, the execution fails, and the file `~/test.log` contains the following snippet:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/square  ' and I am g
oing to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13    }
         
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13    }
         
End of file on the terminal!
```

If I now implement the solution suggested in [the answer cited above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664504/21685), and place a `%` symbol at the point where the deleted comma used to be, so that the `\foreach` structure looks like this:

```
\foreach \i in {
  square%
}{\pic {\i};}
```

and the command `pdflatex test` is rerun, the execution fails, and the file `~/test.log` contains almost the same snippet as shown above, except that the offending key is given as `'/tikz/pics/square '`, i.e. the string `square` is now followed by a single space rather than by two spaces.

1. Why does the execution fail in the third run despite the `%` symbol that follows the string `square` as suggested in the answer cited above?
2. Is this a bug in PGF/TikZ? Should I report this to the TikZ project as a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your defintion of `\placepics` you add a(nother) space after the option that you pass to `\pic` namely between `#1` and the following closing curly brace:

```
\newcommand{\placepics}[1]{ \foreach \i in { #1 } { \pic {\i}; } }
%                                              ^
```

You already found out in [part I of your question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664485/21685) that spaces (except for leading spaces) are not ignored in such an option list that is passed to a `\foreach` macro. The problem is the very same here. So, you really need to take care of spaces in such lists.

Removing this space will solve the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\placepics}[1]{ \foreach \i in {#1} { \pic {\i}; } }
\tikzset{ square/.pic={\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);} }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \placepics{
      square%
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]