# When creating named nodes in TikZ's \foreach, the last node is unavailable outside the loop - what I am doing wrong?

Tags: tikz-pgf

As a part of a larger image, I am trying to create named nodes in a "for element in list" `\foreach` loop, with multiple variables: one specifying the position of the node, on the name of the node.

However, when I try to access created nodes, there is problem with the last node.  Outside the foreach loop it looks like TikZ do not remember that it have created the node, showing
*"Package pgf Error: No shape named `c' is known."*.  There are no problems accessing other nodes.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,draw]

\foreach \x / \nn in { 0.0/a, 1.0/b, 2.0/c }
    \node (\nn) at (\x*2,0) {\nn};

\node (x) at (1.5, -1) {x};
\draw[->] (x) to (a);
\draw[->] (x) to (b);
\draw[->] (x) to (c); %% here LaTeX shows an error

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

https://www.overleaf.com/read/qqnfkghgrrqf

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that Ti*k*Z gets the name of the node as `c_` with a space. Remove the last space in the `\foreach`: ` \foreach \x / \nn in { 0.0/a, 1.0/b, 2.0/c}` .

Comment: Exactly as @JuanCastaño said, do not have a space before the `,` or at the end of your list. [Part 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664485), [Part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664667). (The same problem would arise if you do `0.0/a ,`.